# prompt for user input when running scala program with sbt

Tags: scala, command-line, sbt, user-input

I have a very simple scala program:

```
object TakeInputs {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val name = readLine("What is your name?")
    println(name)
  }
}
```

When I try to run this with
  `sbt "project myproject" "run-main TakeInput"` 
it doesn't wait for user input and the program just finishes with 
`What is your name?null`
as the output.

Is there a way to make sbt wait for user input (like what happens if "readLine" is run in sbt console)? I can provide the inputs as command line parameters but I have a lot of them and I would like to make the program more user-friendly by displaying messages indicating what the user should enter next. Thanks.

Comment: BTW looks like it is now `scala.io.StdIn.readLine`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following to your build.sbt

```
connectInput in run := true
```

From [the sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html#Configuring+Input) in `Configuring Input`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great! I am very new to sbt and I didn't where to look in the documentation.

Comment: I just wasted a few hours trying to figure this out. Thank you.